# Question about normal approximation on roulette

Tags: probability, statistics, approximation, central-limit-theorem, binomial-distribution

Problem: At roulette, you bet a dollar on red $30$ times in a row. Each time you win a dollar with prob. $18/38$ and lose a dollar with prob. $20/38$. Find approximately the probability that after $30$ bets you have at least as much money as you started with. (Use normal approximation)

Attempt:
Let $p = 18/38, q = 20/38$. So for me to win a dollar is a binomial distribution $(30, 18/38)$. I don't know exactly how to set up the probability

Anything helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will end up with at least as much money as you started if and only if you win $15$ times or more.  The number of wins $W$ has a binomial distribution with $n=30$ and $p=\frac{18}{38}=\frac{9}{19}$.  This distribution has mean and variance
$$\mu=np=\frac{270}{19}\ ,\quad \sigma^2=npq=\frac{2700}{19^2}\ .$$
We approximate by using a normal distribution with the same mean and variance,
$$X\sim N\Bigl(\frac{270}{19},\,\frac{2700}{19^2}\Bigr)\ ,$$
and use the continuity correction: since $W$ can only take integer values, $W\ge15$ is the same as $W\ge14.5$.  So the required probability is
$$P(W\ge15)\approx P(X\ge14.5)\ ,$$
and as $X$ is a normally distributed variable with known mean and variance, I am sure that you can evaluate this.

Comment: If I solve my posted inequality I get the result, that x has to be 16 or greater.

Comment: The question asks for you to end up with at least as much money as you started with.  It is obvious that if you win $15$ dollars and lose $15$ dollars, you have the same money as you started with.  It is not necessary to win $16$ times out of $30$ in order to break even..

Comment: You are right. You have to do a small edit in order I can reverse my downvote.